# Can mods delete answers simply because they dislike the contents?

Tags: discussion

A mod recently [deleted my answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/46569/is-it-bad-practice-to-use-your-real-name-online/225103?noredirect=1#comment568070_225103) with the following comment:

> This doesn't answer the question. It's an arbitrary list of what you do and an overly paranoid statement without definition

While it’s possible that some might not like the answer, it did attempt to answer the question in good faith and previously had a positive score. Is it ok for mods to delete answers rather than simply downvoting them or letting the community decide via a 5-person vote?

Answer (score 1):

It has nothing to do with "like". As I said, it doesn't answer the question asked.

Mods are well within their power to delete non-answers despite voting.

And I see that you provided no explanation for *how* it answers the question, you jumped to the inference that it must be something a mod didn't "like".

Comment: A mod can take three actions: flag as “not an answer”, downvote or delete. If you flag the answer 5 people have to agree, after which it gets deleted indeed. Only obvious spam or harassment should get deleted without consulting 5 users.

Comment: Citation needed ... If I answer "cats purr" to a question about encryption, that answer is neither spam nor harassment, but it is a non-answer. A Mod is well within their rights to delete such answers.

Comment: "cats purr" is an obvious non-answer. The answer I've posted is not "obvious" at all. Come on...